# TOKENS transfer

Tags: tokens, wallet-transfer

How do I transfer  Dropil tokens from my Ether wallet to another ether wallet. I tried to search the way to transfer the tokens but did not find the way. Only ether transfer facility is there.

Answer (score 0):

Dropil is an ERC20 Token. You can just transfer it between your ether wallets. For example here, with [myetherwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction). Just choose the token you want to transfer and send it to your other address.